# Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080 : Jenkins Launch Error

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins(1.621) on Windows Server 2008 R2-(Enterprise),from command prompt with option `java -jar jenkins.war`. After installation I tried launch jenkins in google chrome browser. For couple of times I can successfully launch the jenkins, but third time I am getting  the error:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080 : Jenkins Launch Error

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Jenkins, but same result after couple of launch. I am not able to see any logs generated in Jenkins installation directory. (C:\Users\ic003981.jenkins).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Just to mention Error Says : Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080. Installation Directory is : C:\Users\ic003981\.jenkins. I am using Java7 for configuring the jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing new Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.99 m has solved the problem of Jenkins launch error.